# Delphi how to set a variable correctly when using ShellExecute

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

now I have this

```
procedure TForm4.SpeedButton14Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ShellExecute(0, nil,'C:\Users\MyExampleDoc.docx', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

but i need something like this from memo:

```
procedure TForm4.SpeedButton14Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    ShellExecute(0, nil,'Form1.DBmemo1.Text', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    end;
```

how can I insert text from other objects? e.g. Dbmemo or DBEdit

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you wish to achieve. Do you want to create a new Microsoft Word document and put some text in it, from a control on your form?

Comment: No. I have a button that adds the document path to DBMemo1. Now I need a button that launches the document from a link in DBmemo

Comment: If so, just remove the quotation marks: `ShellExecute(0, nil,Form1.DBmemo1.Text, nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`. With the quotation marks, you tell Windows, "Dear operating system, can you open the file "Form1.DBmemo1.Text" for me?", and Windows replies, "Sorry, there is no such file.". Without the quotation marks, you will send the value of `Form1.DBMemo1.Text` to Windows, instead asking, "Dear operating system, can you open the file "C:\Users\MyExampleDoc.docx" for me", and Windows responds, "Certainly, I'd be delighted to do that for you."

Comment: It responds "Incompatible types: 'PWideChar' and 'TCaption'"

Comment: Sorry. You must cast: `ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar(Form1.DBmemo1.Text), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`